# URL Recording with Selenium

Tags: url, selenium, record

i try to write a kind of interpreter for recorded selenium scripts, which translates a selenium script in my own datastructure. In more explenation: Someone records a script with selenium, gives it to me, and i parse it somehow (doesnt matter, this is not the problem here).

The Problem now is, that i really want to group all the actions. Every time the URL changes i want to have a new group with the complete URL as the group name.

The Question is: Can i get Selenium to record the new URL everytime it changes? As a comment, a command or whatever, i dont really care as long as it is in the selenium html file or/and an exported format.

Running the script myself again and recording the URLs is out of question since there could be some crucial database changes recorded.

Answer (score 0):

What about asking the current URL after every step of Selenium? `getCurrentUrl()` http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getCurrentUrl%28%29

Comment: the user who makes the script just works with the Selenium IDE Extension in Firefox, so this had to be called just then. I probably should have mentioned that. Can i tell the IDE somehow to execute this command and save the URL in clear text?